# Memory/Efficiency with Linq and large data sets

Tags: performance, linq, memory

So you know the background I'm coming from, I've been a professional programmer for over twelve years. My best language by far is C# but I've done C, C++, and most recently objectiveC. I've done a lot of work accessing data in databases but I haven't done as much UI work as most people (Except in IOS).

Recently I've begun using the Entity framework in C# for a job and I must say I wish I'd discovered it sooner. I wouldn't say it's the best thing since sliced bread but it's pretty damned close. After using it for a while it got me thinking about best practices and usage as compared to the old school method of using IDBConnections and IDBCommands for everything.

I was coding for a situation where I was going to be listing the contents of a table of users from a database in a bound data grid with the intention of giving the user the ability to do standard CRUD stuff. I started off by making an User class and a IUserManager interface with a corresponding implementation. Each user is assigned to a department and naturally there'd need to be a way to perform CRUD on departments too so I added a Department class, an IDepartmentManager interface and an implementation for that too. I set it up so that the grid bound on the results of the .GetAll() method on the IUserManager interface. Then I started filling in the guts.

I don't have the code in front of me any more but I basically used IDBConnection to tap into the datastore with an IDBCommand using a SQL query. Then I called command.ExecuteReader() and iterated the .Read() method on the IDataReader object. Using the ordinal for each column I pulled out the data, validated it and slipped it into a User class and added the class to a Dictionary that the method would then return. All the DB classes are of course IDisposable so wrapping them in a using takes care of cleaning up the mess.

Pretty standard stuff, I've done it a bazillion times.

That's when I realized that the departmentId I was pulling from the DB wasn't what I wanted to display in my grid. Telling someone 'this guy is in department 7' isn't as useful as saying 'this guy is in accounting'. So I first toyed with modding my query to get both the departmentId and name, and storing the name on the user object for display later. Then I decided to give the user a Department class instance that it would hang onto during it's lifetime that would be populated. That's when I converted the guts to linq.

```
   public Dictionary<int, User> GetAll()
    {
        var result = new Dictionary<int, User>();

        using (var datastore = new myEntities())
        {
            result = (from user in datastore.userInfoes
                       join department in datastore.userDepartmentInfoes on user.departmentID equals department.departmentID
                    select new User()
                    {
                        UserIndex = user.id,
                        FirstName = user.firstName,
                        LastName =  user.lastName,
                        Department = new Department()
                        {
                            DepartmentId = user.departmentID.Value,
                            DepartmentName = department.departmentName,
                                                                                                            },
                        Username =  user.userName,
                    }
                ).ToDictionary(x => x.UserIndex, x => x);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

That's where I started thinking (read: over-analysing probably)

The implementation I had would work just fine. It would even work pretty well for a small dataset. It'll even work fine for a largish dataset (say 10,000). Even if you counted every person in the company I currently work for five times over you'd have less than a thousand people.

But what if for a second I worked for a really big honking company that had 10 million employees? That would result in the departmentName strings being duplicated potentially millions of times.

That also got me thinking that unlike IOS's MVC implementation this particular situation wasn't going to query just enough users to fill the screen and then handle paging and stuff. As soon as the calling code refresh the data binding it was going to pull all 10 million users all at once and pass back the collection. That's going to be slow.

So that leaves me with the idea in my head that this method is both slow and inefficient with larger data sets. Not only that but the fact that there might be 2 million instances of 'Accounting' held with this data set it is going to be a major memory hog. We're also kind of defeating the purpose of a relational database here because of the Department class inside the User. In the DB you just have a departmentId int foreign key referencing an entry in another table. The link only occurs when you cross reference to the other table and even then there's really only one 'Accounting' string at any one time. In the above code you're going to have a whole lot of 'Accounting' strings floating around waiting to be cleaned up.

An MVC scenario would basically 'know' that it takes X number of entries to fill the grid's viewable area. It would only query X at a time starting from index Y and as the user navigated it would query and display additional records as needed. That's a heck of a lot better than querying all 10 million and letting them hang out somewhere whether they're displayed or not.

Like I said, I may very well be over-analysing this. I might also be incorrect in some of my assumptions with the way linq works. But in the interest of learning I figured I had to ask: What is the best way to do something like this? Is this sort of thing ok for small datasets? Would the whole thing be better off as an MCV implementation rather than pulling in the entire dataset to be displayed in the grid?

Answer (score 0):

If you need the whole set of data in memory - you will have to load it anyway. I am sure you will not list 10kk users in a grid, right? The techniques that comes up is paging. Check [this article from msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg650669.aspx) with examples.

As for departments objects, does your `UserInfo` has a foreign key to the department? If so you should just have `userInfo.Department` available to you and no joins are needed.

If you bind the department data to the grid columns, why having the property of `Department` type? I assume your `User` class is something you bind to UI. Flatten it out into:

```
class User
{
 Username 
 UserIndex
 FirstName
 LastName
 DepartmentId
 DepartmentName 
}
```

What is the purpose of `GetAll()`? You return a dictionary and it feels like you need to enable lookups by id. Or do you use the result to enumerate the users?

For lookups, consider talking to the database to get you a single user data when needed. Implement caching if makes sense next.

For enumeration, do not return dictionary - that is all-in-memory object, return IEnumerable with yielded (paged?) results  or even better IQueryable so that calling `GetAll()` doesn't execute the sql call right away, and the calling code can scope the call down by adding necessary filters